# Physics Options keep reverting in smoke sim

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm playing around with the usage of smoke and fire, but every time I try to change and option in the physics tabs, the change is instantly changed back as soon as I select another pane. (See Video in Dropbox)
The same happens in the other tabs E.g. selecting Smoke Adaptive Domain.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Dropbox Link containing MP4:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/elfmy69nhcmr2bz/blender%20bug.wlmp?dl=0